# Xcode 11.4 Quick help in objective-C langage, instead of swift Language, for firebase API with Cocoapods (iOS 13.4 App)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I install Cocoapods in macOS Catalina and Xcode 11.4.1.
It seems to works.

I create a simple projet for using Firebase authentication in iOS 13.4 application.Using UIKit and Swift 5 Language (as normal). 
it works perfectly but I have a problem with Xcode.

When in select a firebase function like Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailAddress, password: password, completion: completion) and select Quick Help to display help, Xcode show me the description of this function in Objective-C language instead in Swift Language.

Here is an image captured.

[image: Xcode quick help captured]

Is it normal or a solution exist to show help in swift Language into a swift projet ?

I'm trying to reinstall et reinit cocoaPods in my projet (pod deintegrate, pod update, etc.), the projet (i.e the iOS Application) continue to work well, but the help for firebase function in Xcode 11.4.1 stays in objective-C, instead of Swift Language.

As you can see in the image, the library file in Pods Directory are .h and .m files (Objective-C)...

I'am a rookie with cocoapods and firebase, sorry if the question is trivial, but I don't find the solution by myself (for now ;-)

Thank you for your help.
Best Regards.

Comment: By the way, if you’re interested in knowing how Objective-C API are translated to Swift (specifically, Swift 3 and later), see [SE-0005](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md).

Answer (score 0):

It shows you the quick help in the language of the underlying pod. Since this particular pod was written in Objective-C, you’ll see Objective-C calling conventions in quick help. If you had another pod which was written in Swift, you’d see the quick help for that pod with Swift syntax.

So, in answer to your question, yes, this is normal.

Comment: Ok, i know that a major part of firebase API are written in Objective-C, but i see other people who have the quick help, ie the description and the type of parameters in swift. So I wonder if it is a question of Xcode or Cocoapods settings ?

Comment: So, you’re saying that you have coworkers who, when they pull up the documentation for the exact same method, see a Swift rendition? Perhaps you can ask them to do a screen snapshot of that and you can include that in your question.